# how to update ng-init variable in template angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display a dynamically concatenated text in my angular js  page.(My aim is to display the id of all users in title ) For that  declared a variable 't' using ng-int and try to update the variable t in a ng-repeat and display 't' as my title (title = {{t}}). Its not update some one suggest me how to do it.
I am expecting an output like

```
<div title ="testID1ID2ID3"> 
 <span>name1\ID1</span>
 <span>name2\ID2</span>
 <span>name3\ID3</span>
</div>
```

But its now displaying

```
 <div title ="test"> 
  <span>name1\ID1</span>
  <span>name2\ID2</span>
  <span>name3\ID3</span>
 </div>
```

Template

```
<div ng-init= "t = 'test';"  title="{{t}}>
  <span ng-repeat = "(key,user) in users" t = "{{t + user.id}}">
    {{user.name}} \ {{user.id}}
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @Sajeetharan I update my Question , Pls check

Answer (score 0):

Please check something like this:

```
<div ng-init= "t = 'test';"  title="{{t}}">
  <span ng-repeat = "(key,user) in users" ng-init = "$parent.t = $parent.t + user.id">
    {{user.name}} \ {{user.id}}
  </span>

</div>
```